# Can you drink tap water in Spain?

Tags: health, spain, tap-water

I'm used to drink the water from our tap, but now we are going to Sevilla and Malaga in Spain.

Is it recommended to drink the tap water in the south of Spain?
Or does it need to be filtered first?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Spain has a well developed sanitation system and associated regulations and controls, and the overwhelming majority of tap water is safe to drink (99.5% in 2018, [according to the ministry of sanitation](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/saludAmbLaboral/calidadAguas/consumoHumano.htm)). There may be some exceptions in remote areas, but in major cities like Sevilla and Malaga you can safely assume tap water is ok to drink unless there's a specific reason to believe otherwise (for example, a tap with sign warning against drinking from it).

As a few people pointed out in the comments, it's best to stick to water from the cold tap for drinking and cooking purposes. Water from the hot tap is probably also fine in most cases, especially in modern buildings or older buildings with modern plumbing/heating systems, but it's less certain. If you're in a hotel or other short-term accommodation you probably don't know the details of the plumbing/heating systems, so sticking to the cold tap is the safe option.

That's as far as safety goes. Whether it's *nice* to drink is a personal decision, the taste varies between regions with different sources and in any region there may well be people who find it to have an unpleasant taste. Bottled water is popular and widely available throughout Spain for those who prefer it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132231/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-h-can-you-drink-tap-water-in-spain). You are welcome to discuss water mains, hot water systems and whether you can drink tap water in that chatroom. (And whatever else seems to fit.)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the sanitation system is mostly well-developed in Spain. Especially on the mainland. The water quality is checked regularly. Of course, there can be regional differences, also, for instance, if you choose to go to one of the islands.

I would also like to point out one more thing, apart from doing some research on the Internet: Use your nose. Does the water smell weird in any way? If yes, use a filter system or at least bring it to a boil. Or buy bottled water in the next supermarket.

Comment: Is it true that the microscopic pathogenic organisms found in water all make it smell? I somehow doubt it.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking more about the smell of chlorine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In and around Barcelona, water is perfectly safe to drink but it generally doesn't taste very nice. Bottled water is easily available and cheap - but you can drink the tap water with no problem at all.

Madrid on the other hand has better tasting water - there's even something of a running joke about how people from Madrid always talk about it has the best water in Spain.